# How to parameterize azure agent.name in azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to parameterize the agent.name in azure pipeline. The objective is to give the user the option to deploy the code in the desired machine. So I have created a pool with a few machines in it and parameterize the agent.name

Code

```
parameters
- name: machinename
  displayName: machinename
  type: string
  values:
  - 10.72.1.123
  - 10.72.1.124

pool:
  name: PoolA
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals ${{ parameters.machinename}}
```

Error :
When trying to run the above code , I get the below error.

```
A template expression is not allowed in this context
```

Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Pool here should define machine which is used to deploy/compile your package/code not the machine where you suppose to deploy. Yoy may try to achieve this, but the original purpose is different. And not evrywhere you can use template expressions, because it has to be known at compilation and not on runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use this workaround:

```yaml
trigger: none

pool:
  name: Default
  demands:
  - agent.name -equals $(machinename)

jobs:
- job:
  displayName: 'Job 1'
  steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline' 
      script: |
        echo "$(machinename)"
```

then please define pipeline variable (on editing pipeline):

[image]

Make this variable available of overwriting:

[image]

and then n running pipeline:

[image]

[image]

You will not get dropdown list, but this is the only way to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Below yaml works.

```
variables:
  vmname: machinename
pool:
  name: poolname
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals $(vmname)
```